# C++ vector template iterator end function

Tags: c++, constructor, iterator

I have a task to write template vector with **separate description**. I want to realize iterator and I have a strange error at end() function.

I have two constructors:

```
template <class T>
Vector<T>::iterator::iterator(Vector<T>& v): vector(v), index(0){}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::iterator::iterator(Vector<T>& v, bool): vector(v), index(v.getSize()){}
```

and begin() and end() realization:

```
template <class T>
typename Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::iterator::begin()
{
    return iterator(*this);
}

template <class T>
typename Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::iterator::end()
{
    return iterator(*this, true);
}
```

In main():

```
 Vector<int>::iterator it(vec);        
        for(Vector<int>::iterator start = it.begin(); start != it.end(); ++start)
        {
            std::cout << *start << std::endl;
        }
```

I have an error:

```
F:\Vector\vector.cpp:281: ошибка: no matching function for call to 'Vector<int>::iterator::iterator(Vector<int>::iterator&, bool)'
     return iterator(*this, true);
```

It seems, I don't understand something. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
template <class T>
typename Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::iterator::begin()
{
    return iterator(*this);
}

template <class T>
typename Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::iterator::end()
{
    return iterator(*this, true);
}
```

You construct an iterator by passing `*this`, but `*this` is a reference to an iterator. And as the compiler says, you didn't define any iterator constructor which takes a reference to an iterator as parameter. Your 2 construtors both take a reference to a vector (not an iterator).
You should do this:

```
template <class T>
typename Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::begin()
{
    return iterator(*this);
}

template <class T>
typename Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::end()
{
    return iterator(*this, true);
}
```

(I removed `::iterator` because `begin` and `end` are supposed to be vector's methods, and not iterator's). Now `*this` would be a reference to a `Vector<T>`.

Comment: I take example of iterator from "Thinking in C++" by B.Eckel (532 page in russian). There are begin() and end() is for iterator, and it seems to be logic...may be I'm mistaken again...

Comment: In the standard library `begin` and `end` return iterators and are called from containers such as vectors, lists, arrays, etc ... But these methods called from iterators, never heard of such a thing

Comment: I see. But if you look closely, the `begin` and `end` methods are defined just after the definition of the nested class `iterator` (see the `;` after the `}`). So these methods are defined in the `Vector<T>` class and not in the `iterator` class.

Comment: @ Unda You're definetly right, sorry. It was not very goog idea to code at night)

Comment: @Padmelina You'll get use to it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This question/answer was very usefull in understanding how to create an iterator within the template. I've expaned the answer to using #define TEMPLATE_ITERATOR(T) typename std::vector<>::iterator

```
#define TEMPLATE_ITERATOR(T) typename std::vector<T>::iterator

// Generic Vector management
template<typename VANY_TYPE>

class GENERIC_VECTOR_MANAGER 
{

private:

protected:

 GENERIC_VECTOR_MANAGER() {}
~GENERIC_VECTOR_MANAGER() {}

public:

std::vector<VANY_TYPE> vtype;

// use the iterator type name as a function argument type name
// difficult/imposible to use "auto arg_any_type_iter" here for the argument type name
virtual bool Act_On_Iter(TEMPLATE_ITERATOR(VANY_TYPE) arg_any_type_iter)
{

 // sample code, the derived class should have specific code

 // validate the iterator before using it
 if (vtype.empty()) { return false;}
     
 if (arg_any_type_iter == nullptr) { return false; }

 if (arg_any_type_iter < vtype.begin()) { return false; }
 if (arg_any_type_iter > vtype.end())   { return false; }

  // Act on arg_any_type_iter

  return true;
}

bool Loop_From_Begin_To_End()
{

 if (vtype.empty()) { return false; }

  // use the iterator type name as a local variable type name
  // "auto a_iter = vtype.begin()" will work here also within the template
  for (TEMPLATE_ITERATOR(VANY_TYPE) a_iter = vtype.begin(); a_iter <= vtype.end(); ++a_iter)
  {
     if (!Act_On_Iter(a_iter)) { break; }
  }

  return true;
}

}; // class GENERIC_VECTOR_MANAGER
```